# Variable typing strategies (hiding vs inheriting abstract generic class vs instantiating generic class)

Tags: java, templates, jpa, generics, inheritance

I can't manage to chose between the following designs as I don't know what their differences are when it comes to allow different type for a same attribute:

1. `abstract class A<T extend G> {T:t}`  
   `class BT1 extend A<T1> {}` 
   This would be inheriting abstract generic class
2. `abstract class A {G:t}`  
   `class BT1 extend A {T1:t}` 
   Thisd would be variable hiding
3. `class A<T extend G> {T:t}`
    this class would then be instantiated as follow : `new class A<T1>`

- What are the differences between those 3 designs ?
- Can JPA retrieve entities with a specific type variable for case 3 ?
- How JPA handle mix of generics and inheritance ?

Comment: It's not clear (*not to me, anyway*) what you are referring to as „*template*“ in this  context. Please, will you elaborate on your meaning of „*template*“? TIA.

Comment: Edited -> I mean generic class

Comment: „*I mean generic class*“ — 1st, do yourself a favor. Stop thinking of Java's parametric polymorphism as  „*C++ templates*“. There is only a superficial similarity. More importantly, it would be valuable for me to understand better what your „*difficulties*“ are when you say: „*I have some **difficulties** to chose between the following designs*“. Please, can you edit your question to elaborate a teensy-weensy bit more on those „*difficulties*“? Please share some sample code of what you have already tried that exposed the different „*difficulties*“? TIA.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :) — „_3. `class A<T extend G> {T:t}`...This would be generic class instantiation_“ —  The (*JLS*) correct terminology for that is: [*Generic class **declaration***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1). The JLS terminology for what you get when you *instantiate* a generic class, is a „[***parameterized type***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)“. Your code examples do not include any *instantiations* of specific *parameterized types*. Only *declarations*.

Comment: Edited, third class is to be instantiated

Comment: Ah! OK. And the concrete class in *#3* is an *alternative* to the abstract class in *#1*. I think I'm with you now. Thanks.

Comment: My answer assumes your *2. `A`* specification _`abstract class A {G:t}`_ means: _`A` has **only** one instance field of type `G`_. And I assumed the *2. `BT1`* specification _`class BT1 extend A {T1:t}`_ means: _`BT1` has **only** one instance field of type `T1`_. I also assumed you're *implying* that each class has accessor and mutator methods that correspond to their respective instance fields. If my assumptions are *incorrect* about what you have specified in your code, then of course my answer would be different. So can you please specify explicitly your intentions RE: _`G:t`_ and _`T:t`_?

Answer (score 0):

> - „*What are the differences between those 3 designs ?…*“

***TL;DR*** —

- Design #1 is „*future-proof*“; it's „*open for extension*“
- Design #2 — *as you've written it* — would fail to compile because *`BT1{T1:t}` IS **NOT** AN `A {G:t}`*
- Design #3 shares one of the „*pros*“ of #1; it's also „*future-proof*“. #3's „*con*“ though is that it's a concrete class

That's based on [*this experiment I did*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_309077) to make that part of your question less abstract/more *concrete* for myself.

---

***The long answer***

This is a case of — *when given a choice of several designs* — choosing the „*best design*“ depends on whether or not your choice *correctly* achieves whatever purpose you *intend* it to serve.

Your second question (*about JPA*) means that your *intention* is probably: „*I want to integrate the data tier of my application with an ORM framework*“.

> - „*Can JPA retrieve entities with a specific type variable for case 3 ?*“

I doubt it. If you think about it, that would be practically impossible for the ORM to manage. Say, for example, you annotated such a class like…

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "IMPOSSIBLES" )
public class A <T extends G > { 
    …
    @Column( name = "CHANGEABLE" )*/    
    private T t;
    …
    public T getT( ){ return t; }
    
    public void setT( T t ){ this.t = t; } 
    …
}
```

And say your application instantiates the following three different parameterized types of *`A< T extends G >`* like…

1. *`A< String > aStringNTT = new A< >( … )`*
2. *`A< Long > aLongNTT = new A< >( … )`*
3. *`A< Date > aDateNTT = new A< >( … )`*
4. …

Then the DDL that you (*or JPA/Hibernate*) would have to write in order for the above to be persisted to the *`IMPOSSIBLES`* table would have to be like…

```
CREATE TABLE IMPOSSIBLES … ( CHANGEABLE VARCHAR(255) OR NUMBER OR DATE OR … , … )
```

No such syntax exists for defining a database table column with dynamically-varying data types. Not in any SQL implementation I'm aware of anyway.

> - „*How JPA handle mix of generics and inheritance ?*“

In my experience, it's handled that mix very well. I implemented this several months ago…

```
import javax.persistence.*;    
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractPersistableCustom<PK extends Serializable> implements Persistable<Long> {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable#getId()
         */
        @Override
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        protected void setId(final Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        …
}
```

…and JPA handled persisting this and several other concrete *`@Entity`s* successfully…

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey_says")
public class Question extends AbstractPersistableCustom<Long> {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "survey_id")
    private Survey survey;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("sequenceNo")
    private List<Response> responses;    
    …
}
```

Comment: A deep thank you for  your detailed answer, I will study it

Comment: „*A deep thank you for your detailed answer...*“ — And a *deep* you're welcome @AlixHumbert :) If you don't have time to respond to nothing else in the above answer, please *at least* respond to this: „*please edit your question with code that shows what you have tried already*“. TIA.